# If there is n number of hyphen in between two words, how to remove n-1 hyphen between words

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose there is a string like :

```
abc--def-ghi & jkl---mno
```

it should replace with :

```
abc-def ghi & jkl--mno
```

I tried:

```
slugName = $(this).val().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '-').replace(/[\-]+/g, '-')
```

Comment: Include your attempt in your question please.

Comment: Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.

Comment: your question should at least demonstrate that you tried to solve the problem by yourself first, by including the attempts you did, and the problems you encountered for example.

Comment: slugName = $(this).val().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '-').replace(/[\-]+/g, '-')

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 MVC c# with javascript, jquery.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Use to find n hyphens and a hyphen (eg. (----)(-))

```
(-*)(-)
```

and replace it with the result of the first expression

```
$1
```

leaving you with n-1 hyphens. Tested in sublime edit

Comment: but `-*` can match _zero_ hyphens too, can't it?

Comment: @sudo_O As per the title, the OP wants to _remove_ n-1 hyphens, which leaves one.

Comment: i don't want to replace it with single hyphen, i want to replace it with n-1 hyphen and if there is single hyphen want to replace it with space and thanks for your reply. Waiting for expected answer.